# filling data gaps with monthly averages (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, average, interpolation

I have a very long time series over 10 years with half-hourly measurements as Csv file. Every now and then the measurement device break down. I want to interpolate this gaps either with the monthly average or a moving average (which neglect missing values). I guess I need a for-loop to do this but I have no Idea how to do this exactly. Could anybody help me?
My data look like this:

```
10-Oct-2010 21:15   0.00271
10-Oct-2010 21:45   0.00408
10-Oct-2010 22:15   -0.00228
10-Oct-2010 22:45   0.00433
10-Oct-2010 23:15   0.00421
10-Oct-2010 23:45   0.00224
11-Oct-2010 00:15   -0.01678
11-Oct-2010 00:45   -0.00059
11-Oct-2010 01:15   -0.00371
11-Oct-2010 01:45   0.01353
11-Oct-2010 02:15   0.00108
11-Oct-2010 02:45   0.00101
11-Oct-2010 03:15   -0.00159
11-Oct-2010 03:45   0.0011
```

my current code is:

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.read_csv('C:\Python27\Scripts\ET_T_2000.csv', sep=';', parse_dates=[['date', 'time']])
ts1 = ts.set_index('date_time')['ET'].resample('D', how='sum')
ts1.to_csv('sum.csv')
```

So i get the daily sum of my evaporation data. I can resample the monthly daily average as well but I don't know how to tell Python it need to use for each gap the meanvalue for this specific month.

Comment: I'd propose to interpolate the missing values from the two surrounding values; that should be closer to the real missing value than a monthly average.

Answer (score 1):

In case you've got your values in a list (alas, you didn't state your data structures) of tuples `(timestamp, value)`:

```
data = [ (1, 3.), (2, 5.), (3, 0.), (6, 3.), (7, 3.), (9, 2.), (10, 0.) ]
timestampDistance = 1

def interpolateGap(ts0, v0, ts1, v1):
  count = (ts1 - ts0) / timestampDistance
  return [ (ts0 + i * timestampDistance, v0 + (v1 - v0) * i / count)
    for i in range(1, count) ]

def fillGap(data, pos, ts0, v0, ts1, v1):
  data[pos+1:pos] = interpolateGap(ts0, v0, ts1, v1)

for i in range(len(data)-1, 1, -1):
  timestamp, value = data[i]
  previousTimestamp, previousValue = data[i-1]
  if previousTimestamp + timestampDistance < timestamp:
    fillGap(data, i-1, previousTimestamp, previousValue, timestamp, value)

print data
```

This will print

```
[(1, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (3, 0.0), (4, 1.0), (5, 2.0), (6, 3.0), (7, 3.0), (8, 2.5), (9, 2.0), (10, 0.0)]
```

Comment: well, I have a csv file with 160,000 entries. The missing values are somtimes several days (which means one day = 48 measurements which are missing), sometimes several weeks. I think this solution is only for a short series, isn't it?

Comment: I don't see a reason why even a million entries should pose a problem.  But of course, interpolation won't simulate typical daily curves.  You will get a straight line from one existing point to the next only.

Comment: Okay thanks for your effort! As far as i understand it, it build averages from the last known value and the next value after the gap, correct? I have two Questions: 1) is it possible to fill the gap with the monthly average (or 30 day moving average), because this would be more accurate? 2) My data are originally in a csv file which i need to import to python. If i use "data = pd.read_csv('ET_T_2000.csv', sep=';', parse_dates=[['date', 'time']]) I get an error "KeyError: u'no item named 187055'". the csv file has 187057 rows. do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Of course you can compute a monthly average and use this to fill any gap, but that's more complicated (and this is not a site for developing solutions but just for answers to questions).  Concerning the KeyError: sounds like another question you should ask here (do not mix all problems into one question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Note: This should be a comment but I don't have the rep for it :)

Pandas has a nice 'interpolate' function on both series and dataframes: (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html#interpolation). I'm going to suggest, especially if you have 'several days' of missing data, that you just leave the values as NaNs (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html#working-with-missing-data). Pandas has really nice support for plots with NA values and seeing a plot that has the correct measurement values and then a 'gap' is easily to interpret. Also that approach gives additional information, lets say that you're looking at the plots and you see that the weekends have more gaps than other days, that might indicate the measure device is less stable on the weekend (or whatever).

Comment: Yes, thank you. I know this interpolation function of pandas, but it uses only some values before and after the gap. this is too inaccurate. the data represant evaporation in a forest. If for some days the device broke down and it interpolate just the values before and after the gap then I don't get the course over the day and it's in general to inaccurate.

Comment: I agree that for your use case interpolation might not be what you want that's why I suggested just leaving the data as NA values. Pandas has great support for it and functions like 'mean,min,max,std' will all work well (do the right thing) with NA values. If you replace the missing values with 'monthly average' than all of those stats will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

With such big gaps of missing values, I guess you're really better off, to keep them as NANs, and adjust your calculations, that they can deal with missing data. Looks like you're doing financial simulations with it, and in the long run, it will always backfire, if you modify the actual raw data. In case you're using Numpy for the calculations, [Bottleneck](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Bottleneck) adds a bunch of modified functions, that skip NAN values in arrays, e.g. when calculating means and so on. Better go on with that!

Answer (score 0):

**Don't whatever you do, change your source data**: always keep original data as it is.

Any consumers of the data can then decide on a particular interpolation scheme relevant to what the data are showing and what they intend to do with it.

In particular, if you are doing some volatility analysis of the data then your putting in interpolated values will have the effect of artificially *reducing* that volatility.

(**PS** you say you have a Character Separated Value file, but what is the delimiter?)

Comment: the delimiter is ";". I need to interpolate it cause I want to sum up all values per year to create a water balance. This values are evaporation data. If i build a cumulative sum for a year with so many missing values, the sum will be much to less below the real evaporation. So I need to interpolate.

Comment: (I don't see any delimiters in the file). In this case then, consider computing your sum (`s`) and the number of recorded times (`t`) and scaling that to the whole year using `s * p / t` where `p` is the potential number of records.

Comment: Maybe you should sum the existing values, count them and then use their mean value to estimate what the sum for a complete year would have been.  Interpolating here could grossly falsify the value if data dropout is correlated to extreme values (e. g. if the sensor always breaks when the water is extremely high) because then the interpolation would extend the extreme value to a longer time period than it actually was.